# "Sequence contains no elements" when using .Any()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This seems like a straightforward question.  I am beginning to suspect a bug in razor.

```
if (Model.athleteImages .Any()){
//some code

}
```

I have replaced the above with the following:

```
    if (Model.athleteImages.Count > 0)
    {
        var i = 0;
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        while (i + 1 < Model.athleteImages.Count())
        {
            i++;
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="@i"></li>

        }
    }
```

This always throws "Sequence contains no elements" for collections with no elements e.g. Count() = 0.

Any() is supposed to test if a Sequence contains elements.  That is its entire purpose.

I have also tried

```
if (Model.athleteImages.FirstOrDefault().[fieldName] != null){
//some code

}
```

Same result.

here is some relevant code from the controller for those wondering what the Images   collection is

```
var adImages = from i in db.athleteImages
    where thisAd.albumId == i.albumId
    where i.deleted == false
    select i;

viewModel.athleteImages = athleteImages.ToList();
```

Here is the View Model Class

```
public class ListingViewModel
{
    public site site { get; set; }
    public userAd userAd { get; set; }
    public List<athleteImage> athleteImages { get; set; }
    public string categoryName { get; set; }
    public int categoryId { get; set; }
    public string subcategoryName { get; set; }
    public int subcategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Stack Trace

```
[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1 source) +269
   ASP._Page_Views_userAds_Listing_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\Bill\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CuriousMarketplaces\CuriousMarketplaces\Views\userAds\Listing.cshtml:32
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +198
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +173
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651116
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: So, what type is `Model.Images`? Where does it come from? How do you populate `Model.Images` in the first place?

Comment: More info needed, because this shouldn't happen. BTW `Model.Images.FirstOrDefault().[fieldName]` is a surefire recipe for a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Please check your code for some place that uses `Single()` or `First()`. Those seem to be the primary cause of this error, and if that first line you posted there is indeed where the exception is being triggered, perhaps your `.Images` property is calling one of those methods as a side-effect?

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks, I've checked that, but I am not using either Single or First on the Images collection.

Comment: I agree with @JLRishe, the stack trace clearly states that a call to `System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1 source)` is causing this issue. You should be able to test by removing any code that uses Linq from the view.cshtml, and remove the using namespace reference for System.Linq.

Comment: The stack trace seems to be saying that the error is on line 32 of your Listing.cshtml file. Can you show us what's in the vicinity of line 32?

Comment: @danludwig I'll give that a shot later today and update with results.

Comment: init athleteImages collection in your constructor.

Comment: @JLRishe line 32 is nothing but the closing curly brace of my "if" block.

Comment: @BillHarris Could you show us what's inside the `if` block, then?

Comment: @JLRishe I get the error regardless of what is in the if block, but I have included it anyway.  If there is even one item in the collection, the code runs fine.

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks to you and Dan for insisting that I look for First() and Single(). That was the hint I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If what you really care about is whether or not there are any images in the collection, something like this might make more sense:

```
if (Model.Images.Count > 0) {

}
```

Comment: That was the first thin I tried.  Unfortunately, it yields the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Any() will throw an exception if the source is null, this is documented behavior and how it is supposed to work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Dave's solution is pretty good but I would add a null check, Count will also throw an exception if the object is null.

```
if(Model.Images != null && Model.Images.Count > 0) {

}
```

Comment: So it will throw `ArgumentNullException` in this case. This is not what OP is reporting.

Comment: @spender Apparently I should read better. I can't get that same behavior to replicate, just created a test project in MVC razor with a base class. It either throws ArgumentNullexception when the Sequence is null or it works fine when the count is 0.

OP what exactly is Images field on your model?

Comment: Yes. I can't see how this would happen too. OP needs to provide more info.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt attention folks. Model.Images is coming from a ViewModel.  The Images collection is an IEnumerable of type Image.  The Image class is a POCO class in my models folder.  I have tried testing for null.  I need a surefire way of testing to see if the collection has any elements.  Any() is by definition supposed to do that (at least that's what intellisense claims). I have also tried Count.

Comment: I should add that the code runs fine if there is even one Image object in Images.  Thanks again everyone.

Comment: I absolutely cannot get the behavior to replicate, even inside an MVC view with a full mockup like you described it.  Any  IEnumerable<T> class works fine with Any() even with 0 count.

Can you post the full ViewModel class for us and the full exception (including staack trace)? There is something going on behind the scenes here

Comment: @BillDinger I have added the ViewModel class and the stack trace.  Originally I used simply "Images" for the name of the connection.  As I am posting more detail, I have switched to the real name which is "athleteImages." I have done other MVC sites wherein I tested for existence of elements in a view (usually with .Count), and this is the first time I have seen this behavior.  I agree with you; I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Dan gave me the hint I needed.

Even though the debugger was indicating that the error was occurring at the closing block of my if block, that was not the case.

In a later block of code in the same view, I have this:

```
<div class="item active" id="0">
    <div style="width:400px;height:300px;text-align:center;background-color:black;">
        <img src="/Content/Images/Deals/1/@Model.athleteImages.First().fullImage" style="height:300px;" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            some caption
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To fix the problem, I need to test again. so:

```
if (Model.athleteImages.Count > 0) 
{
<div class="item active" id="0">
    <div style="width:400px;height:300px;text-align:center;background-color:black;">
        <img src="/Content/Images/Deals/1/@Model.athleteImages.First().fullImage" style="height:300px;" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            some caption
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

What fries my brain is that the error message indicated a problem at line 32.  In reality it was on line 37.

Comment: That makes sense now, and confirms the 2nd line in your stack trace ((System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1 source) +269)) Line numbers can be off if you have the optimize code checked